# Javascript not working. compare strings and change id content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code which is supposed to get the content of a div. and then compare to a string and if they are equal change the content on that div.

```js
var strs = document.getElementById('prodAvailable').innerHTML.toLowerCase();
var stra = "GS2023".toLowerCase();
if(stra == strs) {
document.getElementById('prodAvailable').innerHTML = "milk";
}
```

```html
<div id="prodAvailable" class="Value"> GS2023 </div>
```

Comment: Your issue is 2 extra spaces on each side of `GS2023`

Answer (score 1):

it doesnt work because the string in your div has spaces in the beginning and end of the string. you might want to trim the string prior to comparison.

```js
var strs = document.getElementById('prodAvailable').innerHTML.toLowerCase().trim();
var stra = "GS2023".toLowerCase();
if (stra == strs) {
    document.getElementById('prodAvailable').innerHTML = "milk";
}
```

```html
<div id="prodAvailable" class="Value"> GS2023 </div>
```